# PHP-FPM: unable to write files with fopen() after upgrading to APC

Tags: unix, nginx, php

PHP is running as user "nginx", but I'm unsure of how to edit write permissions for this user.

PHP will execute fine, but fopen() and writing to the error_log will not work. The default setting was "php" as the user, which yielded the same results.

This was working fine before, but things seemed to break while upgrading to APC.

Configure command:

```
'./configure' '--build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-t1lib=/usr' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-xml' '--with-system-tzdata' '--with-mhash' '--enable-fpm' '--libdir=/usr/lib64/php' '--without-mysql' '--disable-pdo' '--without-gd' '--disable-dom' '--disable-dba' '--without-unixODBC' '--disable-xmlreader' '--disable-xmlwriter' '--without-sqlite' '--without-sqlite3' '--disable-phar' '--disable-fileinfo' '--disable-json' '--without-pspell' '--disable-wddx' '--without-curl' '--disable-posix' '--disable-sysvmsg' '--disable-sysvshm' '--disable-sysvsem'
```

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a permissions issue that was fixed by changing the owner of the folder to the user running php (in this case, "nginx").

```
chown -R nginx /home/html
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution! However, you can set which user runs nginx and php-fpm. I have them running as nginx and www-data respectively.